# The uniqueness of the Airy equation, which is a third-order linear partial differential equation.

Tags: integration, analysis, partial-differential-equations, periodic-functions

For the Airy equation, which is a third-order linear partial differential equation given by:
$$ \partial_{t}u+\partial_{xxx}u=0.$$

Suppose furthermore that we consider solutios of Airy equation which are spatially periodic $$u(x+L,t)=u(x,t)$$
for a given period $L$ and for $(t,x)$ in $[0, \infty) \times \mathbb{R}.$ Show that there is at most one such solution u corresponding to a given smooth, periodic initial condition $u_0: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ without using separation variables.

This is my effort:

Suppose $u, v$ both satisfy Airy equation, then $w=u-v$ obeys
$$\partial_t w=\partial_{xxx}w $$
$$w(x+L,t)=w(x,t)$$
$$w(x,0)=0$$

Note that $\partial_t w.w=\dfrac{1}{2}\partial_tw^2$ then $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\partial_t w.w dx=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\partial_t w^2dx.$$

On the other hand,
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\partial_{xxx} w.w dx=[w_{xx}.w]\Big|^{+\infty}_{-\infty}-\int_{\mathbb{R}}w_{xx} w_xdx.$$

Do $w_{xx}.w=0$ on the boundary? And am I on the right track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. Notice that these functions may not be integrable on the entire line, so we will consider these integrated quantities on just a single period, say $[0,L]$. By periodicity, if we find that $w=0$ on $[0,L]$, then $w=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

We constrauct $u$, $v$, and $w$ as in your post, then we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \frac{1}{2}\int_0^L w^2~\mathrm{d}x &= \int_0^L ww_t~\mathrm{d}x \\
&=\int_0^L w w_{xxx}~\mathrm{d}x \\
&=\left.[w w_{xx}]\right|_0^L-\int_0^L w_x w_{xx}~\mathrm{d}x \\
&=\left(w(L)w_{xx}(L) - w(0)w_{xx}(0)\right) - \frac{1}{2}\left(w_x^2(L) - w_x^2(0)\right),
\end{aligned}
$$
where the last term comes from noticing that $2w_xw_{xx} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(w_x^2)$. Now since $w$ is smooth and periodic, all of $w$'s derivatives are also periodic with period $L$, so this expression is zero. We then have

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \frac{1}{2}\int_0^L w^2~\mathrm{d}x=  0,
$$
so $\int_0^L w^2~\mathrm{d}x$ is constant in time. However, since $w_0=0$, we find that $\int_0^L w^2~\mathrm{d}x=0$ for all time, so we have that $w=0$ on $[0,L]$ for all time. since $w$ is periodic with period $L$, we find that $w$ is identicially zero for all $x$ and $t$.

Comment: Thank you very much, but could you explain to me why these functions may not be integrable on the entire line?

Comment: Consider simple examples like $\sin x + 1$ and $\sin x$. Neither is integrable on the entire real line for different reasons.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I want to be sure that I understand your idea that in this case of the Airy function, we can integrate it on $\mathbb{R},$ right? But it is sufficient to only consider the interval $[0, L].$

Comment: The only periodic function whose integral on $(-\infty,\infty)$ converges is the zero function. A function has to decay for its integral to converge, and a function can't decay and be periodic.

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much.